# iOS7 device get restarted when using 'saveEvent:span:commit:error:' method

Tags: iphone, ios7, ekeventstore

I am developing an application which copies appointment records from my app to devices native calendar. I am using the following code to do that.

```
NSString *eventIde = nil;

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKCalendar *calendarDef = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
[event setCalendar:calendarDef];

//set values to this event. like title, notes, startDate, endDate, location

NSError *err1 = nil;    
BOOL isStoredd = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err1];

if(isStoredd){
       eventIde = [NSString stringWithString:event.eventIdentifier];  
}
```

Here I am creating EKEvents for each appointment in my app, sets appropreate values, and saves the event to event store. This is done simultaniously for about 200 records.It was working fine in iOS6, when i updated the ipad to iOS7 it causes the device to restart. I tried the same with record count 50, then also same issue occured.

Sometimes it shows an over memorry problem, sometimes shows 'Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination'. I need the eventIdentifier to enter into my database for further use. But everytime this issue occures and device restarts.

Can anybody help me with this problem? What is special with iOS7 eventstore?
Or please advice any solution to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Comment: If you run the import sequentially does it work?

Comment: If you disable ARC to trace the memory functions, might be able to find something by following the release.

Comment: @RyanR - I didn't get you Ryan, what you mean my 'import sequentially'? The above code block is working for each record. I tried to batch the changes, and commit them at last. But this will not allow to access eventidentifier.

Comment: @StephenJ - I am not using ARC. But I cannot trace anything.

Comment: You said _this is done simultaneously for about 200 records_. Simultaneously means concurrent. So, have you tried executing it serially, or even just a single record to test? And what do you mean it will not allow access to event identifier? You won't get a memory notification from accessing a property.

Comment: Ok, forget tracing for now, how many times do you alloc/init the store?

Comment: @StephenJ - If there is 200 records, then 200 times. Each record will pass through the above block of code.

Answer (score 0):

The first section of the Calendar and Reminders programming guide on Apple.com has your answer.

You do not allocate the store multiple times unless you have more than one Calendar, like FB events.

I highly recommend Apple's guides, they're easier than 3rd party books oftentimes.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I tried this by initializing eventstore in my appdelegate method, and used this eventstore for each record. But the problem is still there. So now i am copying maximum of 30 records at a time to the calendar. Then i set a timer to copy the next 30 records after 30 seconds. Thus i finish copying all my 200 above records to calendar in some minutes. This solved my issue. Is that a right method?